# Total pages in a report using Report Viewer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I want to get the total number of pages in a form, which is placed in Report 
Viewer..

I used this code, actually the report has 5 pages but I got only one page.

```
int t=int T = objReportViewer.LocalReport.GetTotalPages();
```

How can I make it give me all 5 pages?

Answer (score 2):

In C# with ReportViewer 2010, a

```
reportViewerName.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
```

did the job for me.

PS: Just seen, this thread is more than 1 year old, sorry!

Comment: Thanks - this fixed an issue for me - I was always getting 2 ? as the total pages. Didn't know about this property which must default this value in version 8.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for providing an answer to an "old" question. As long as it's valid info, it's worth the effort of putting it here. People looking for an answer to similar questions end up here through search engines anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Globals.TotalPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157274(SQL.90).aspx)?

Example for a text box: `=Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages`

Comment: Darn you for getting in before me and getting the rep due for this answer!