# reportviewer.LocalReport.GetTotalPages() returns sometimes 1 or 2

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

In my [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application I'm using a user control, and added my report viewer and a custom toolbar. I want to create a custom navigation for it as well. But, for some reason when I want to check the total number of pages to decide whether or not to show the navigation buttons, it sometimes returns 1 or 2...
I've ran out of ideas and not quite sure where to go from here..

**code here**

```
if (rvReports.LocalReport.GetTotalPages() > 1)
{
    liFirst.Visible = true;
    liPrevious.Visible = true;
    liNext.Visible = true;
    liLast.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of pages can vary with the data in the report or even for the same data by the connected/selected printer. If the page count is based on the Form, it might even vary by the size of the form or the resolution of the display. If you wonder why it's sometimes 1 and sometimes 2, you should find out whats different, maybe even print the report for each case and look at it. You won't get any results from looking at the page count number alone.

Comment: LocalReport.GetTotalPages() is returning me with value 1 or 2 withe the same data and with  the same resolution display.So now can you explain the reson of this unexpected behavoiur.

Comment: When does it return those values? If you start it twice? If you call it twice in a row? What would happen if you called rvReports.LocalReport.GetTotalPages() 100 times in a row, would the results be consistent or would they vary?

Comment: Maybe anything [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767713/total-pages-in-a-report-using-report-viewer) might help. Apart from googling the problem, if it's giving different results on different calls, I'd file a bug for it.